# Highlight Lyrics with playing mp3 song (Synchronized form)

Tags: android, media-player

Hi I have created Activity with Media Player for playing mp3 songs with lyrics displayed in textView .
now i need to highlight that lyrics with playing mp3 song in synchronized way.
please help.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) - it allows to use some HTML-formatting in your String to highlight text (b, i, ..). There is a tutorial about this at this [blog](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/08/easy-method-for-formatting-android.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Spannable s = (Spannable) textview1.getText();
```

Then

```
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(any color),preStart,preEnd,               Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```